# ListView and Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview

With putDate method in main, I have a method called updateStudentDate in dbManager class that get id and date, and when I click on save button the ids that i got from database and current date is sent to updateStudentDate.
but error occur.

This is main activity.

```
public class StartAttendance extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private DBManager dbManager;
    private List<UserModel>  students;
    private String studentSubjectId;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_attendance);

        final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        final Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        final ListView listOfTakeAtt = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfTakingAttendance);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
         studentSubjectId = intent.getStringExtra("studentSubjectId");


        dbManager = new DBManager(StartAttendance.this);
        dbManager.open();
        ArrayList arrayList2 = dbManager.getAllStudentsName(Integer.valueOf(studentSubjectId));//Get the names from database.


        students = new ArrayList<>();

        setData(arrayList2);


        final CustomLayoutOfTakingAttendance adapter = new CustomLayoutOfTakingAttendance(this, students);
        listOfTakeAtt.setAdapter(adapter);

        listOfTakeAtt.setDividerHeight(17);


        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);


        listOfTakeAtt.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                UserModel model = students.get(i);

                int y=model.isSelected?1:0;

                model.setSelected(true);

                students.set(i, model);


                if(y==1){
                    model.setSelected(false);
                 }


                adapter.updateRecords(students);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList arrayList2){
        for(int i=0;i<arrayList2.size();i++){
            students.add(new UserModel(false, (String) arrayList2.get(i)));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
            switch (v.getId()){
                //When save button is clicked i want to see present radioButton is checked or not for each item.
                //if checked save current date into database for this id.
        case R.id.save:
           putDate();
            break;

        case R.id.cancel:
                Intent i=new Intent(StartAttendance.this,ContentOfEachSubject.class);
                i.putExtra("studentSubjectId",studentSubjectId);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
}

    public void putDate(){
        SimpleDateFormat DateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date d=new Date();
        String date=DateFormat.format(d);

        boolean isUpdated=false;
        UserModel model;
            ArrayList arrayList1 = dbManager.getAllStudentsId(Integer.valueOf(studentSubjectId));//Get the ids from the database.
            for(int i=0;i<students.size();i++)
            {
                 model = students.get(i);

                if(model.isSelected){
                    dbManager = new DBManager(StartAttendance.this);
                    dbManager.open();
                    isUpdated = dbManager.UpdateStudentDate((Integer) arrayList1.get(i), date);
                }
            }

        if(isUpdated){Toast.makeText(StartAttendance.this,"You took attendance successfully..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);}

        else {Toast.makeText(StartAttendance.this,"Fail while getting attendance!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);}
    }
}
```

UserModel class

```
public class UserModel {

    boolean isSelected;
    String name;


    public UserModel(boolean isSelected,String name) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }



    public String getStudentName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

dbManager class

```
public boolean UpdateStudentDate(int id,String date){
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_STUDENT_DATE,date);
       long result=database.update(DatabaseHelper.STUDENT_TABLE,cv,DatabaseHelper.KEY_STUDENT_ID+" = "+id,null);
        databaseHelper.close();
        if(result==-1){return false;}

        else return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide us some kind of log where error is described ?

Comment: Bro when i click on save button the app is stopped automatically the errors is not shown.

Comment: Even logcat is empty ? (Android Montior tab)

Comment: 03-21 09:18:12.093 6150-6150/com.example.jihad_eng.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Process: com.example.jihad_eng.test, PID: 6150
                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer                                                                              at com.example.jihad_eng.test.StartAttendance.onClick(StartAttendance.java:114)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)                                                                              at android.view.View

Comment: $PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Bro I think the error is in putDate method, when i get the ids(arraylist) by a for and send  to database.

Comment: Error is on line 114 of StartAttendance.java file, could you please copy-paste this line here ? Cause you have not included imports to your code so I got it little bit messy right now

Comment: boolean isUpdated = dbManager.UpdateStudentDate(arrayList1.get(i), date);

Comment: Bro the line in method putDate() please check.

Comment: the arraylist1 is already is an integer type, i don't understand why the error say can not cast from string to integer.

Comment: Well, I think the issue is on line `isUpdated = dbManager.UpdateStudentDate((Integer) arrayList1.get(i), date);` where you are casting a value retrieved from array list, which is not typed (ie. `ArrayList<Integer>`), hence Lint won't warn you about this potential issue. Could you paste here implementation of `DBManager.getAllStudentsId` method ?

Comment: //Get all student ids.
    public ArrayList getAllStudentsId(int id){
        ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList();
        String[]columns=new String[]{DatabaseHelper.KEY_STUDENT_ID};
        Cursor cursor=database.query(DatabaseHelper.STUDENT_TABLE,columns,DatabaseHelper.KEY_STUDENT_SUBJECT_ID+" = "+id,null,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(cursor.isAfterLast()==false){
            arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_STUDENT_ID)));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in implementation of `getAllStudentsId(int id)` method.
If your IDs are suppose to be of type Integer, I'd suggest you to change signature of method to return not `ArrayList`, but `ArrayList<Integer>`. It would be even better to return some generic type of list, such as `List<Integer>` is.

However, the main issue is, that within this method you are adding to collection `String` instances, instead of `Integer`s.

```
arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Databas‌​eHelper.KEY_STUDENT_‌​ID)));
```

I don't know how data are persisted in DB, whether your IDs are numeric or varchar format, but I guess it should be enough to change `cursor.getString(...)` to `cursor.getInt(...)`

Then, implementation of this method could be like

```
public List<Integer> getAllStudentsId(int id){ 
    List<Integer> result =new ArrayList<>(); 
    String[] columns = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.KEY_STUDENT_ID}; 
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.STUDENT_TABLE, columns, D‌​atabaseHelper.KEY_ST‌​UDENT_SUBJECT_ID + " = " + id, null, null,null,null); 

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){ 
        result.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Databas‌​eHelper.KEY_STUDENT_‌​ID))); 
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

Also, don't forget to change type of your list within `StartAttendance.java` class.

```
List<Integer> arrayList1 = dbManager.getAllStudentsId(Integer.valueOf(studentSubjectId));//Get the ids from the database.
```

Comment: <3 <3 Thank you brother you found the error, i don't know how i thank you.

Comment: Just upvote the answer and mark it as correct one :) You're welcome

Comment: Sorry bro I have not 15 reputation now, later i will do :) thanks.